# Pycharm не видит опубликованную на PyPI библиотеку

Tags: python, pycharm, pypi

Опубликовал библиотеку на PyPI, в поиске там же она отображается, через pip устанавливается. Но PyCharm при поиске библиотек её не видит, так же её нет в `pip search`. В чём может быть проблема?

Название библиотеки: `youtube-video-search-with-api`

upd: в `pip search` таки находится.

Comment: Может быть в кешировании их поиска, может она там чуть позже появится, ну как вариант...

Comment: Думаю, вопрос можно закрывать, так как библиотека успешно устанавливается.

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский у меня не находит

Comment: @вася https://pypi.org/project/youtube-video-search-with-api/

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский *в поиске там же она отображается, через pip устанавливается. Но PyCharm при поиске библиотек её не видит*

Comment: @вася и даже тут работает: https://i.imgur.com/z4KoKvJ.png.

Comment: i.imgur.com/bZHF1Co.png я про это.

Comment: @ДаниилЧижевский вы точно прочитали моё сообщение?

Comment: @вася как оказалось, нет :)

Answer (score 1):

Была такая же проблема. В пайчарме нажимаешь View -> Tool Windows -> Terminal и там вводишь командy pil install и твоя библиотека. Далее перезаходишь в PyCharm, и она появляется.

Comment: да, установить библиотеку в venv можно, как и просто через pip, мне просто интересно когда и при каких условиях добавленная библиотека отображается в поиске библиотек. может верификация какая нибудь требуется, или время на индексацию. но плюсую за способ.